# How can I make this twitter bot work? Python 3.8

Tags: python, windows, twitter, bots

I have all kinds of problems with this code, this is a large portion of another stackoverflow user's code, but I'm assuming they might have never finished it, because I get all kinds of errors.  Famously, 'Status' object has no attribute 'replace.'  Which I THINK I have fixed, no idea, couldn't find anything on it online, although it was a variable so I tried the non variable version and still nothing.  Now I have this problem.

```
Yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\alexo\Desktop\Twitter Dad.py", line 28, in <module>
answer="@"+tweet.user.screen_name+" Hi " + c + ", I'm Dad!"
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str
```

Don't know what is wrong with this, the point of the script is for this bot, to search for when someone's tweet starting with "I'm ____" and respond with "Hi ____, I'm dad!"  Just a humorous thing, but I'm totally lost.  All help is appreciated, thank you!

New problem!

```
    import tweepy
    import tweepy as tt
    import time
    import sys
    import importlib 
    from importlib import reload
    importlib.reload(sys)

    #login credentials twitter account
    consumer_key = 'redacted'
    consumer_secret = 'redacted'
    access_token = 'redacted'
    access_secret = 'redacted'

    #login
    auth = tt.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
    api = tt.API(auth)
    search_query = "hi I'm Dad"
    user = api.me()
    print(user.name)

    max_tweets = 100

    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=search_query).items(max_tweets):
    c = tweet
    c = ("im ","")
    answer="@"+tweet.user.screen_name+" Hi " + c + ", I'm Dad!"
    print("Reply:",answer)
    api.update_status(status=answer)
    time.sleep(300) #every 5 minutes

Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "C:\Users\alexo\Desktop\Twitter Dad.py", line 26, in 
    tweet_contents = tweet.split() # assuming tweet is a str
        AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'split'

Error:

```
       Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\alexo\Desktop\Twitter Dad.py", line 26, in <module>
       tweet_contents = tweet.split() # assuming tweet is a str
       AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Code

```
import tweepy
import tweepy as tt
import time
import sys
import importlib
from importlib import reload
importlib.reload(sys)

#login credentials twitter account
consumer_key = '4QGxdJFmn4phBS0z9JTMU1S27'
consumer_secret = 'VuOkfqCEq6YcEeI2Sg6hhP4a7xrMHbhzORr9gQKyX8XfETbbnX'
access_token = '1200414502304591872-lj89lAd7r8oFbXEwDaVxg7YnH8pddO'
access_secret = '3PUfawYhaQJYDU6VYriKiVZNA9zYAAc1UOXe1UREgtWH7'

#login
auth = tt.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tt.API(auth)
search_query = "hi I'm Dad"
user = api.me()
print(user.name)

max_tweets = 100

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=search_query).items(max_tweets):
    tweet_contents = tweet.split() # assuming tweet is a str
i = tweet_contents.index("I'm")
c = tweet_contents[i + 1]
answer = "@{name} Hi {c}, I'm dad!".format(name=tweet.user.screen_name)
print("Reply:",answer)

api.update_status.(status=answer)
time.sleep(300) #every 5 minutes
```

Comment: Why is `c` a tuple? What are you trying to do there?

Comment: The indentation of your code is missing

Comment: `c = ("im ","")` is probably your problem.  Any reason why you assign `c=tweet` and then immediately reassign it to ` ("im ","")`? Also consider using string formatting.

Comment: That was part of the other user's code, and I'm new and it didn't make much sense to me either but I didn't know what to do with it.  Thank you for explaining!  Now I just need to figure out how to make it tweet the word after "I'm".  Right now it just tweets @example_name
 Hi ('im ', ''), I'm dad!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no apparent reason `c` should be assigned to a tuple, so I'll assume that is removed and replaced with the tweet content.

That said, you should use Python's build in [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples) rather than string concatenation.

```
# Using the .format() function:
answer = "@{name} Hi {c}, I'm dad!".format(name=tweet.user.screen_name, c=c)

# Using an "f-string":
answer = f"@{tweet.user.screen_name} Hi {c}, I'm dad!"
```

**EDIT**

Per comment from OP:

> Okay so I got it to tweet now thanks to you! But it only tweets @JohnnyAppleseed Hi ('im ', ''), I'm dad! Do you know how I could get it to quote whatever came after "I'm"? Only thing I changed was the .format() line. Thank you so much!

To grab whatever comes after the string `I'm` in the source tweet, you'll need to first find the index of the word `I'm`, then pull the word that follows it. Forgive the variable names, I'm commuting.

```
tweet_contents = tweet.split() # assuming tweet is a str
i = tweet_contents.index("I'm")
c = tweet_contents[i + 1]
```

For example, if the tweet was "I'm sad", this would split that into a list, `["I'm", "sad"]`, then get the index of "I'm" at 0, then get "sad" from index 0 + 1.

Comment: Okay so I got it to tweet now thanks to you!  But it only tweets @JohnnyAppleseed
 Hi ('im ', ''), I'm dad!  Do you know how I could get it to quote whatever came after "I'm"?  Only thing I changed was the .format() line.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Updated per request

Comment: Thank you for the update, so now I'm having a problem figuring out how to apply this, sorry for being annoying if I am, you are being extremely helpful!  This is the error.  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alexo\Desktop\Twitter Dad.py", line 26, in <module>
    tweet_contents = tweet.split() # assuming tweet is a str
AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Yeah so it has to be a `str`, so reference whatever the tweet content is on that `Status` object.

Comment: I edited the original post to explain better.  I'll try that.